# Cipher, text wrapping

Tags: c, text, word-wrap

I am working on a piece of homework based on a cipher, I have the key and the message in separate arrays. I want to create a third array that will contain the key wrapped around to fit the size of the message, like so:

```
message
keykeyk
```

Have been struggling with this one for a while, any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The `strlen()` function and modulus operator (`%`) will help.

Comment: something like `wrappedKey[i] = key[i % keyLength]` where `0 <= i < messageLength`

Answer (score 0):

something like `wrappedKey[i] = key[i % keyLength]` where `0 <= i < messageLength` – Drew McGowen